# Optimizing hierarchical query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a deep hierarchical model that looks like this:

Accounts
 -> Venues
   ->Events
     -> Guest lists
       -> Tickets

And I need to do a query where I select tickets based on parent guest lists OR events OR venues OR accounts, so it would look something like this:

**Query:**

```
select * from user_detail ud, venue v, event e, guest_list g, ticket t

where

    t.guest_list = g.id
    and g.event = e.id
    and e.venue = v.id

    and (
        ud.guest_list = t.guest_list
        or ud.event = g.event
        or ud.venue = e.venue
        or ud.account = v.account
    )
```

This of course is a very costly query, and since I have millions of tickets - this is not working out quite as I was hoping.

**Non-ideal solution (storing redundant parent references at ticket level)**

The solution I am thinking about is to optimize this by storing not only the direct parent but all super-parents in the tickets row, so instead of only referencing the guest list table, I would also reference the parent events, venue and account for every ticket.
Even though this would be quite simple to accomplish, this means I would store redundant data and changing the parent could be troublesome and error-prone.

**Ideal solution (whatever that does not require redundant data)**

Any suggestions here?

Comment: Do you really need to select every column from every one of those tables? If not -- which table(s) do you actually need to select from?

Comment: I only need to select from the user_detail table, but I still need to join on the other ones to do this hierarchy traversal, dont I?

Comment: also, spend some time learning ANSI SQL JOIN syntax, it will pay huge dividends in the long run!

Comment: @PiotrBlasiak: Not necessarily. Ideally, the only tables in your `FROM` clause should be (1) tables you actually need to `SELECT` from and (2) tables that serve as `JOIN`-bridges between the tables you actually need to `SELECT` from. Any other tables would ideally be relegated to subqueries (especially in `IN` and `EXISTS` clauses). Sometimes performance considerations force you to use `JOIN`s instead of subqueries -- but sometimes it's subqueries that perform better. Therefore, you can't optimize a query without knowing what it actually needs to return.

Comment: I am actually letting hibernate do the queries for me, so sorry if my sql is not optimal but I didnt think that is the issue here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the most popular ways to improve performance of `OR` is just to use `UNION ALL`.

So split your query into 4 (each one with only one join) and `UNION ALL` them

Also, I hope that `t.guest_list`, `g.event`, `e.venue` and `v.account` are covered with indexes, aren't they?

Comment: Would it really help here? I think the problem is that I need to traverse the hierarchy from the bottom up for every ticket

Comment: try not to think of it as a traversal problem, what you're actually doing is set based - the criteria you choose simply include or exclude a given record from the set. Provided your database is well indexed I would expect the above approach to be *very* quick, each of the four sets that you `UNION ALL` together should be very fast to retrieve.

Comment: @Piotr Blasiak: sure it would. Your current issue is that you currently have conditional joins implemented by `OR`. `OR` even on one table cannot be optimized much, but when you work with joins - it becomes to hell

Comment: Ok, but the ticket table only has a reference to the guest list table. So to fetch all tickets for a specific account would still require me to do all those joins and I thought that was the big problem?

Comment: @Piotr Blasiak: `OR` is a problem, join with `ANDs` in `ON` clause - isn't (if you have your columns indexed properly)

Comment: @zerkms any other suggestions without using UNION? I am using an ORM (JPA/Hibernate) that does not support those.

Comment: @Piotr Blasiak: hehe, you either use handy tools or have the fast queries ;-)